# How to speed up event confirmation email?

Tags: rng

I recently setup a Drupal 8 instance to set up a special event website. I am allowing users to build inline contacts to register for an RNG event. Everything seems to be working: The users offer their email and username, and the contact is created; then, they register for the event and the registration is created. Twelve hours later, they get an email message setup using the Courier and Rules integration with RNG.

Is there a way to speed up the confirmation email?  If I send an email from a user contact form on the same website, it sends it immediately. I imagine it is a Courier/Rules issue with how often the email queue is being processed, but I cannot figure out where that is configured.

Comment: I would probably phrase more than a Yes or No question in the future. I think that you have provided enough information for someone to provide an answer based on Courier and Rules. But I think one pending question for you is what your cron interval is setup for?

Answer (score 1):

Courier message dispatch is all done in cron. Therefore, in order to speed up the delivery of messages, you should run cron as often as possible.

Personally I run it every 30 seconds, but every 1-5 minutes should be fine in most cases.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of both the [RNG](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng) and the [Courier](https://www.drupal.org/project/courier) modules.

Comment: If you run cron that often, you might want to use a module like Ultimate Cron so you don't have to run every cron job that often. Some can be quite slow and shouldn't be run that often.